# Resize canvas para convertirlo en imagen con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Me gustaría poder exportar un **dibujo pixel art** de un canvas HTML a imagen, pero al estar en 108x108px la imagen se ve borrosa, necesitaria convertir el canvas a un tamaño mayor sin perder la escala.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red'; 
ctx.fill();

document.write('<img style="width:300px;" src="'+c.toDataURL("image/png")+'"/>');
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="108" height="108" style="width: 300px; height:300px;">

</canvas>
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué el canvas es tan pequeño?

Comment: Porque es para generarlo con código. Y hacerlo directamente en el tamaño que quiero se me crashea el navegador.

Comment: cualquier juego que ejecutes en el navegador va a usar canvas de 1000x1000 pixels sin problema, dudo que sea el problema ¿qué error te da?

Comment: Yo no quiero ejecutar un juego, yo quiero crear pixel art y exportarlo en imágenes.

Comment: Te has centrado en la parte menos importante: el tamaño del canvas puede ser 4K y no debería darte problemas